# File upload control for each row inside gridview

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function AverageCalculation() {
        var TtldgvRows = $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtGridviewRows").val();
        var MonthValue1 = 0;
        var MonthValue2 = 0;
        var MonthValue3 = 0;
        var percentageValue = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < parseInt(TtldgvRows); i++) {

            MonthValue1 = $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_dgvCurrentPerformance_txtMonth1_" + i.toString()).val();
            MonthValue2 = $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_dgvCurrentPerformance_txtMonth2_" + i.toString()).val();
            MonthValue3 = $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_dgvCurrentPerformance_txtMonth3_" + i.toString()).val();
            if (MonthValue1 == "") {

                MonthValue1 = 0;
            }
            if (MonthValue2 == "") {

                MonthValue2 = 0;
            }
            if (MonthValue3 == "") {

                MonthValue3 = 0;
            }

            percentageValue = (parseFloat(MonthValue1) + parseFloat(MonthValue2) + parseFloat(MonthValue3)) / 3;
            $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_dgvCurrentPerformance_lblAverage_" + i.toString()).text(percentageValue.toFixed(2));

            if (percentageValue > 80) {

                $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_dgvCurrentPerformance_imgBtnFileUpload_" + i.toString()).hide();
            }
            else {
                if (parseInt(MonthValue1) != 0 && parseInt(MonthValue2) != 0 && parseInt(MonthValue3) != 0) {
                    $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_dgvCurrentPerformance_imgBtnFileUpload_" + i.toString()).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function FileuploadClick() {
        var TtldgvRows1 = $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtGridviewRows").val();

        for (var i = 0; i < parseInt(TtldgvRows1); i++) {
            $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_dgvCurrentPerformance_fupCurrentPerformance_" + i.toString()).click();
            return;
        }
    }

    function getFile() {
        var TtldgvRows1 = $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtGridviewRows").val();
        var lblFileName;

        for (var i = 0; i < parseInt(TtldgvRows1); i++) {
            lblFileName = $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_dgvCurrentPerformance_fupCurrentPerformance_" + i.toString()).val();
            $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_dgvCurrentPerformance_lblFileUpload_" + i.toString()).text(lblFileName);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Gridview Control

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView3" runat="server" Width="100%" align="center" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="#4B3333"
    HeaderStyle-BackColor="#C4EAC5" PageSize="10" AllowPaging="false" CssClass="table table-bordered table-hover dataTable no-footer Content"
    AutoGenerateColumns="false" EmptyDataText="No Record(s) found" DataKeyNames="ID"
    OnRowDataBound="dgvCurrentPerformance_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Objective Name" ItemStyle-Width="15%">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblObjectiveName" runat="server" Style="text-align: center" Text='<%# Eval("ObjectiveName") %>'></asp:Label>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnID" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Measurement Name" ItemStyle-Width="15%">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblMeasurementName" runat="server" Style="text-align: center" Text='<%# Eval("MeasurementName") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Target" ItemStyle-Width="15%">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblTarget" runat="server" Style="text-align: center" Text='<%# Eval("Target") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CA Plan" ItemStyle-Width="15%">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblCAPlan" Style="text-align: center" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CAPlan") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="M1" ItemStyle-Width="15%">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtMonth1" runat="server" Width="80" CssClass="form-control" Text='<%# Eval("Month1") %>'
                    onkeypress="return ValidateKeyText(event)" Style="text-align: right;"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="M2" ItemStyle-Width="10%">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtMonth2" runat="server" Width="80" CssClass="form-control" Text='<%# Eval("Month2") %>'
                    onkeypress="return ValidateKeyText(event)" Style="text-align: right;"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="M3" ItemStyle-Width="10%">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtMonth3" runat="server" Width="80" CssClass="form-control" Text='<%# Eval("Month3") %>'
                    onkeypress="return ValidateKeyText(event)" Style="text-align: right;" onkeyup="AverageCalculation();"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Average" ItemStyle-Width="10%">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblAverage" runat="server" Enabled="false" Text="" Style="text-align: center"></asp:Label>
                <asp:Image ID="imgBtnFileUpload" runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/upload-button-icon-64365.png"
                    Width="30px" Height="30px" onclick="FileuploadClick();" ToolTip="Click here to upload"
                    Style="text-align: right" />
                <asp:FileUpload ID="fupCurrentPerformance" runat="server" onchange="getFile();" Style="text-align: center; display: none;" />
                <asp:Label ID="lblFileUpload" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="<center>Action</center>" Visible="false">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <center>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="hylEdit" runat="server" CssClass="fa fa-pencil fa-fw" CausesValidation="false"
                    ToolTip="Edit" OnClientClick="return Edit();" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"
                    title="Edit" OnClick="hylEdit_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="hylDelete" runat="server" CssClass="fa fa-trash-o fa-fw" CausesValidation="false"
                    ToolTip="Delete" OnClientClick="return Delete();" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"
                    title="Delete"></asp:LinkButton>
            </center>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="<input id='chkAll' onclick='checkAll();' type='checkbox'>All"
            ControlStyle-Width="10%" HeaderStyle-Width="10%">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <center>
                <asp:Label ID="dgvlblIsCurrentPerformance" runat="server" Style="text-align: center;
                    display: none;" Text='<%# Eval("IsCurrentPerformance")%>'></asp:Label>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkUserID" runat="server" CssClass="checkbox" onchange="CheckOther();" />
            </center>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Measurement ID" ItemStyle-Width="15%" Visible="false">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblMeasurementID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("MeasurementID") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Client ID" ItemStyle-Width="15%" Visible="false">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblClientID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ClientID") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Objective ID" ItemStyle-Width="15%" Visible="false">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblObjectiveID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ObjectiveID") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: I see a whole lot of code but no actual question. What is it that you are asking?

Comment: What happened to the fileupload?